# Does <canvas> have a way to set a transparency index on a PNG?

Tags: html, canvas, transparency

I want to use canvas to dynamically alter the transparency index of images, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways depending on what you want to accomplish.

Firstly **if you just want to display an image with a color for the transparency, you don't need canvas.** You can just add CSS styling to the image:

```
<img src="theURL" style="background-color: red;">
```

Lets say you do want canvas though. The most efficient way is to just draw the color first and then the image.

Another way is to draw the image to the canvas, set the globalcompositeOperateion to 'destination-over' and then fill the area of the image with the color you want.

```
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over'
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,280,210); // if the width and height are 280x210
```

See it in action here, replacing a transparent background with blue:

http://jsfiddle.net/MEHbr/327/

I would advise against using `getImageData` and `putImageData` unless you need the fine per-pixel control, as they are much slower.

For saving the image, canvas2Image has the best options:

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: +1 Nice demo, Ill have to remember that. I just assumed per pixel so suggested put/getimagedata this is a good solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible you have to use `getImageData` and `putImagaData`

**[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)**

```
imageData = canvasContext.getImageData( 0, 0, canvasContext.canvas.width, canvasContext.canvas.height );

for( i = 0; i < imageData.length; i+= 4 ) {
        imageData[i+3] = opacityValue;
}

canvasContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0 );
```

Heres an example that does what your looking for, (also what the above snippet was taken from)

http://labs.josh-ho.com/getImageData/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class for your canvas and create css to style it:

```
.canvas_class{  
 -moz-opacity:0.5; /* For older FF versions */  
 -khtml-opacity:0.5;  
 opacity:0.5;  
}
```

You can then use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library to modify the DOM live:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

I hope this helps you add changeable transparency to your canvases :D

Comment: This will alter the transparency of the canvas overall, OP is looking to modify the alpha component of the image data.